# Time Needed to Diagonalise Matrix with sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

I am trying diagonalize a 5x5 matrix with `sympy` for a physics problem. Using numerical values seems to be reasonably fast, but because I have a lot of symbols in the matrix to diagonalize, it's taking a very long time. What is the time complexity (and name) for the algorithm used in `sympy`? How long will it take? Could it actually need a million year?

`H` in the following code is the matrix

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.quantum.constants import hbar

# define symbols
w = sp.Symbol('omega')
e = sp.Symbol('e')
r = sp.Symbol('r') 
E_e = sp.Symbol('E_e')
E_t = sp.Symbol('E_t')
E_x = sp.Symbol('E_x')
E_y = sp.Symbol('E_y')
n_1 = sp.Symbol('n_1')
n_2 = sp.Symbol('n_2')
n_3 = sp.Symbol('n_3')


# construct matrices
t2_x_e = sp.Matrix([[0, (5/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*n_3*((8*sp.pi)/15)-n_1*(3**(-sp.Rational(1,2)))*sp.sqrt(2)*(15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*((4*sp.pi)/15)], [0, (3**(-sp.Rational(1,2)))*sp.sqrt(2)*(15/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*n_3*((8*sp.pi)/15)+n_2*(3**-sp.Rational(1,2))*(15/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*((8*sp.pi)/15)], [(3**(-sp.Rational(1,2)))*sp.sqrt(2)*(15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*n_3*((4*sp.pi)/15)-n_2*(3**-sp.Rational(1,2))*(15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*((4*sp.pi)/15),0]])
t2_y_e = sp.Matrix([[((5/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2))*(n_3)*((8*sp.pi)/15)-(n_1)*(3*sp.Rational(-1,2))*(sp.sqrt(2))*(15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2)*((4*sp.pi)/15),0],[(-3**sp.Rational(-1,2))*(sp.sqrt(2))*((15/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2))*n_3*((8*sp.pi)/15)-n_2*(3**sp.Rational(-1,2))*((15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2))*((4*sp.pi)/15),0],[0,(3**sp.Rational(-1,2))*(sp.sqrt(2))*((15/(4*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2))*n_3*((4*sp.pi)/15)-n_2*(3**sp.Rational(-1,2))*((15/(16*sp.pi))**sp.Rational(1,2))*((8*sp.pi)/15)]])

H = sp.BlockMatrix([
    [(E_t + hbar*w) * sp.eye(3), e*E_x*r*t2_x_e + e*E_y*r*t2_y_e ],
    [(e*E_x*r*t2_x_e + e*E_y*r*t2_y_e).T, E_e * sp.eye(2)],
]).as_explicit()
```

Comment: I haven't found any discussion of complexity in `sympy` docs.  There's more to this than the algorithm and its 'raw' complexity.  Doing math on those symbolic terms is be much slower than on numbers.  `timeit` on `H[3,2]-H[4,2]` is 400µs compared `ns` for a numeric difference.  Applying `simplify` to that increases the time 10x.

Comment: It's much more than just `O(n)` to worry about here. The eigenvalues of a 5x5 matrix with symbolic entries can not in general be expressed analytically using ordinary expressions due to the Abel-Ruffini theorem. The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial and formulas for the roots explode as you go from quadratic to cubic to quartic. There is sort of a quintic formula but it's so big I've never seen it. You're lucky that your charpoly has a linear factor so the remaining eigenvalues can be expressed using the quartic formula.